# function pointers with different prototypes in c

Tags: c

Here is the code i was trying.I could not comprehend the output i got.Why is output some garbage value here and not 10?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void f(int);
void (*foo)(float)=f;
int main()
{

  foo(10);
   return 0;

}

void f(int i)
{
   printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

**Output is some garbage value.**

Comment: [Did you enable all warnings and then compile it?](http://ideone.com/iWyra) It tells you why.

Comment: It did give warning but it just said incompatible.thats all.

Comment: Read warnings!  They are your friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour.

You're calling `f`, which is a function taking an `int`, as if it were a function taking a `float`.  The actual behaviour will depend on how the calling conventions of your platform work - for example, if `int` and `float` parameters are passed in the same register or the same stack slot the result will be that of aliasing the floating-point bit pattern representing `10.0f` as an `int`.  If on the other hand `int` and `float` are passed differently the result will be whatever garbage was in the appropriate register or stack slot.

Also, because this is undefined behaviour the compiler is at liberty to do whatever it likes, and if the optimiser is enabled it may well do.

Comment: What if stack is used for parameters?is stack not used for that purpose at all in any platforms?

Comment: Absolutely it is; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions for some of the possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is output some garbage

Because you lie to the compiler.

You tell it `foo` is a pointer to a function that accepts a `float` ... but then point it to a function that accepts an `int`.

**Don't lie to the compiler**

Comment: +1 Best advice. But perhaps one day mankind will triumph over the savage compiler!

Answer (score 4):

Compiers usually emit warnings or errors in this case, e.g. GCC says:

```
program.c:4: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

Intel C Compiler is more verbose:

```
program.c(4): warning #144: a value of type "void (*)(int)" cannot be used to initialize an   entity of type "void (*)(float)"
  void (*foo)(float)=f;
                     ^
```

Besides possible conversion of argument value `10` to floating point, there is another option if you are running on a 64-bit machine - calling convention. Integer arguments are passed through the regular integer CPU registers (`RDI`, `RSI`, etc.) while floating-point arguments are passed in the SSE registers (`XMM0`, `XMM1`, etc.). Even if somehow the floating point value was compatible with the integer one, the called function will receive its argument in different register (`XMM0`) than the one it will consult for the value (`RDI`).

On a 32-bit machine both integer and floating point arguments are passed on the stack. What you end up with is `1092616192` which is just `10.0` in IEEE 754 single-precision floating point representation:

```
1092616192 = 0|10000010|01000000000000000000000
             | |        |
             | |        +---> significand = 1 + 2^(-2) = 1.25
             | |
             | +------------> exponent = 130 - 127 = +3
             |
             +--------------> sign = 0 (positive)

1.25 * 2^3 = 1.25 * 8 = 10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of undefined behavior.

The call through `foo()` converts the integer `10` to `float`, which is then interpreted as an `int` by `f()`.

I'm pretty sure this isn't well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the different prototypes. The compiler treats "10" as a float, and uses its floating-point representation to call `f()`, which in turn treats it as an ineteger, whose binary representation does not have the value "10".